# ImageMagick: Achieve multiple (and partially *conditional*) operations on an image with one single command

Tags: imagemagick

Sorry if my question is not a complex hard question but i tried a lot and didn't achieved what i expected :(

How do i use ImageMagic to achieve all these goals at the same time (win32):

1. Resize (scale) image ONLY if the (width/height) is bigger than 1000px so that the resulting image's max width/height is 1000px or less
2. Convert any type to JPG with 90% quality
3. Place a Trade mark in right bottom of the image (not required but it's better to have it)

Thanks for sharing you knowledge and experiences

Comment: What have you tried so far? IM's documentation is quite extensive and I'm certain you can find out how to do these things by browsing the docs and maybe a bit of online searching.

Comment: Hi yes i did but everytime a bit is missing i did all separately but i'm looking for a single command

Comment: Why do you need to do everything with a single command? Why not multiple commands? Also, please modify your post and put what you have tried so far.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline: It's rather obvious that the OP does not need this for a single conversion only, but for batch-converting lots of files. If you are able to do that in a single command, you may save lots of CPU power, lots of time, lots of RAM, lots of disk space for writing temporary files to disk and lots of additional efforts to clean up the temp files again.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you want the aspect ratio being preserved if the resize operation should happen for the bigger images.

```
convert              \
  input-image        \
 -resize 1000x1000\> \
 -quality 90%        \
  output.jpg
```

**Please not the `\>` suffix to the `1000x1000` geometry setting! It is crucial.** If you skip it in your command because you've overlooked it, then the command will not work as expected.

This command should fulfill your first two points. Key in the resize parameter is the `\>` addition to the usual `{width}x{height}` part. It tells ImageMagick to only resize the input file if either of width or height are more than 1000 pixels. (The `\` is only there as an escape to keep your shell from interpreting the `>` as a redirection command.)

To include the 3rd point, there are a ***lot*** of different kinds of 'watermarks' I could imagine. I'll show only a very simple one here:

```
convert              \
  input-image        \
 -resize 1000x1000\> \
 -quality 90%        \
  \
       -fill white             \
       -undercolor '#00000080' \
       -gravity southeast      \
       -annotate +5+5          \
        ' My Trademark '       \
  \
  output.jpg
```

I hope this example gives you enough of an idea in order to continue with your own experiments.

---

### Update

As Jimmy B. thinks my command does not work, let me proof my case with an example...

#### Create three example images

```
for i in 2000x2000 2000x500 500x2000; do
   convert -size $i  xc:red  red-${i}.jpg
done
```

#### Check the example images' size

```
identify red-*x*.jpg
  red-2000x2000.jpg JPEG 2000x2000 2000x2000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 23.7KB 0.000u 0:00.000
  red-2000x500.jpg[1] JPEG 2000x500 2000x500+0+0 8-bit sRGB 6.29KB 0.000u 0:00.000
  red-500x2000.jpg[2] JPEG 500x2000 500x2000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 6.29KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

#### Resize the three example images with my command

```
for img in red-*x*.jpg; do
   convert              \
     ${img}             \
    -resize 1000x1000\> \
    -quality 90%        \
     \
          -fill white             \
          -undercolor '#00000080' \
          -gravity southeast      \
          -annotate +5+5          \
           ' My Trademark '       \
     \
    resized-${img}
done
```

#### Check the resized images' size

```
identify resized-red-*x*.jpg
  resized-red-2000x2000.jpg JPEG 1000x1000 1000x1000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 7.43KB 0.000u 0:00.000
  resized-red-2000x500.jpg[1] JPEG 1000x250 1000x250+0+0 8-bit sRGB 3.31KB 0.000u 0:00.000
  resized-red-500x2000.jpg[2] JPEG 250x1000 250x1000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.99KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer but it converts every image to 1000X1000 it's not what i mean, i mean if image was 2000x500 (horizontal) or 500x2000 (vertical) or 2000x2000 (square) resize the image so that the final image's maximum width or height is 1000 so images will be 1000x250 or 250x1000 or 1000x1000 for example.

Comment: @JimmyBrosnan: Hey, my command works perfectly the way you wanted it! I'm using ImageMagick version **`6.8.9-8 Q16 x86_64 2014-10-03`** on Mac OSX. What's ***your*** version?!? Run `convert -version` to find out.